# CRF algorithm implemented in x264

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-encoding

Where I can find CRF algorithm implemented in x264? I want to study the default rate-distortion algorithm in ffmpeg and x264.
I'd appreciate any comment.

Comment: x264 is an open-source codec: https://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html

Comment: tnx. that helped

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to search "Variance Adaptive Quantization"